# Strategy to have multiple validations for the 'same' class

Tags: java, validation

Let's say I have a class `Address` and it is a child of both `Contact` and `Vendor` classes. In the case of `Contact`, the business only really cares about the Address's *City* field to be required (Contacts are more about the person's name and phone and their location - City).   Whereas, for a `Vendor`, who may get paper mail from us, we want full address information, so *Line1*, *City*, *State/Province*, *Country*, *PostalCode/Zip* are all required.

My thought was to create a `ContactAddress` that uses `@NotBlank` on the *City* field, and then a subclass `VendorAddress` that decorates more fields with `@NotBlank`.

I'm just not certain this is the best approach (and it complicates my domain objects and Hibernate mappings). Does anyone have hints for the right pattern?

EDIT: further details

```
public class Contact {
 private Address address;
}

public class Vendor {
  private Address address;
}

public class Address {

  private String line1;

  @NotBlank
  private String city;

  private String state;
  private String country;
  private String postalCode;

}
```

`Address` then, can only have `@NotBlank` on *City*, because not all uses of Address require the other fields.

I should also say, I want to use these classes in JSF (which does that 'validation for free' thing, in addition to manually invoking it in my service layer). This is a "traditional" JSF/Spring/Hibernate app.

Maybe I want to use http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups ? Not sure how this interacts with JSF's 'free' validation

Comment: "it is a child of both Contact and Vendor" means they are both interfaces it implements, or both are part of the same hierachy of classes (i.e Address extends Vendor extends Contact?)

Comment: @Disco3: It sounds to me like it's a field within both `Contact` and `Vendor`.

Comment: I can't really get your design, could you provide the classes' signatures?

Comment: sorry guys, more details provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this, I'd like to provide my own answer.  What I eventually figured out, and it works for my case, is that indeed, Validation Groups are how you go about this.

And as for how it interacts with JSF's validations, there's a f:validateBean tag that lets you control that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should separate the concern of *holding* the data from *validating* the data - as the latter is context-specific. You may well want to put some "core" validation into `Address`, but then separate out the other validators into `ContactAddressValidator` and `VendorAddressValidator` classes (possibly implementing some sort of `Validator<T>` interface).

This is the same approach as you take to sort the same type in different ways, implementing `Comparator<T>` multiple times for the same `T`, but in different classes.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a popular approach if you're into JSR-349 (Java Validation Framework), which we are, for better or worse.  Or could they still be combined?